# The traveller of the world

Tags: riddle

I have travelled around the world,
But only in one girl’s eyes.
Some say it’s true, others not,
Quite different, have I got.
Truth be told, I am lost,
But I lived another life, in her mind.
A man spared a child sadness,
And taught a lesson with it too.

Who am I?

Answer (score 2):

It could be ( partial one)

> the famous *penny black* ( postal stamp)

Which

> travelled around the world, when it was in use, the girl - being a relative/ herself - Queen Victoria

Some say it’s true, others not,
Quite different, have I got.

> Perhaps, people argue - if it is really she!

Truth be told, I am lost,

> Not sure...on this part

But I lived another life, in her mind.

> As a queen, definitely she lived a different life, mentally.

A man spared a child sadness,
And taught a lesson with it too.

> Not sure on this part.

Comment: Good idea, you’re on the right lines!

Comment: @RohitJoss Then I'd recommend adding the knowledge tag to your riddle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm close or very far...

> Amelia Earhart?

I have travelled around the world,
But only in one girl’s eyes.

> She tried to fly around the world, but only she and her co-pilot know if they did.

Some say it’s true, others not,
Quite different, have I got.

> It is a little bit of a mystery.

Truth be told, I am lost,

> Still lost.

But I lived another life, in her mind.

> Maybe she landed on some island and lived a life with the native people.

A man spared a child sadness,
And taught a lesson with it too.

> ???

Comment: DVL 10 Good answer, but not the one I’m looking for.